# I updated Unity IAP to update Google PBL, but can't log in Google Play Service at phone after uploaded at Play Console Internal test

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

At first, I'm not a native English speaker, sorry for poor English skills. Also I started studying Unity and programming basics few months ago, so easy word explanation would be very grateful.

I was asked to update PBL library of active mobile game by my friend, due to programmer's absence. This game works well in current version with mobile services and paying function, but needed to update Google PBL, due to their policy.

I first studied about Google Console and PBL, and recognized Unity has own IAP package, so I updated Unity IAP to 4.10.0 which supports PBL 5. Also, I saw the codeless IAP button become deprecated, so I changed component to new one without OnProductFetched function. It seems working well in Editor, fake store pops up and purchasing was possible. So I build APK and uploaded in Google Play Console internal test track, but after I installed it in my phone, I cannot log in to Google Play Game.

Please, does anyone knows what I am missing? I was searching all days long but couldn't find the answer. I updated build number, version, and uploaded obb, symbols, APK correctly. I have no idea because I just updated package and some IAP button components, unrelated to sign in.

Updated Unity IAP to 4.10.0 to support Google PBL 5

Changed codeless IAP button components, due to deprecated components.

Uploaded at Google Play Console internal test, after seeing it works in Editor.

I expected to log in Google Play Games at my phone, but it couldn't. I can't confirm changed components works well.